# variables for different objects of same type made in constructor all referencing the same object

Tags: python, list, object, constructor, instantiation

this is my first time posting here and also I'm new to Python,so please be patient with me if I'm something wrong! I've seen a similar question to this but couldn't see a clear solution. This must have a simple solution but it has frustrated me all day.

I'm trying to make multiple objects of the class 'Slot' inside the constructor
of the class 'Board'. After each object is made, I'm appending it to a list.
Finally I'm going through each object in list and calling 'getHandles' method, which should
output their unique results. Instead the results of last slot object made are displayed.

Board class constructor :

```
class Board:
slots = []

def __init__(self):
    slot1 = Slot(1); self.slots.append(slot1);
    slot2 = Slot(2); self.slots.append(slot2);
    slot3 = Slot(3); self.slots.append(slot3);
    slot4 = Slot(4); self.slots.append(slot4);
    slot5 = Slot(5); self.slots.append(slot5);
    slot6 = Slot(6); self.slots.append(slot6);
    slot7 = Slot(7); self.slots.append(slot7);
    slot8 = Slot(8); self.slots.append(slot8);
    slot9 = Slot(9); self.slots.append(slot9);

    print("\nprinting slot objects in list 'slot'\n");
    counter = 0;
    while counter < len(self.slots):
        print("slot number :"+str(self.slots[counter].getPosition()));
        print("slot value :"+str(self.slots[counter].getHandles()));
        counter +=1;
```

slot class constructor :

```
    #Slot class constructor
def __init__(self,n):
    self.setPosition(n);
    positions = coords.getLargeGridPosition(n);
    self.U[2] = positions[1]; self.D[2] = positions[2];
    self.L[2] = positions[3]; self.R[2] = positions[4];

    print("made slot object : "+str(self.getPosition()));
    print("handle values: ");
    self.getHandles();
    print(" - ");

def getHandles(self):
    print(" U:"+str(self.U)+" D:"+str(self.D)+" L:"+str(self.L)+" R:"+str(self.R));
```

This is what I get when I make a 'Board' object :

1st part out output (making slots and appending in Board constructor):

```
>>> b = Board()
made slot object : 1
handle values: 
U:[1, 2, 2] D:[2, 1, 20] L:[3, 4, 10] R:[4, 3, 12]
- 
made slot object : 2
handle values: 
U:[1, 2, 5] D:[2, 1, 23] L:[3, 4, 13] R:[4, 3, 15]
- 
made slot object : 3
handle values: 
U:[1, 2, 8] D:[2, 1, 26] L:[3, 4, 16] R:[4, 3, 18]
- 
made slot object : 4
handle values: 
U:[1, 2, 29] D:[2, 1, 47] L:[3, 4, 37] R:[4, 3, 39]
-
```

and so on for all nine objects.
2nd part out output (calling getHandle method for each object in list) :

```
printing slot objects in list 'slot'

slot number :1
U:[1, 2, 62] D:[2, 1, 80] L:[3, 4, 70] R:[4, 3, 72]
slot value :None
slot number :2
U:[1, 2, 62] D:[2, 1, 80] L:[3, 4, 70] R:[4, 3, 72]
slot value :None
slot number :3
U:[1, 2, 62] D:[2, 1, 80] L:[3, 4, 70] R:[4, 3, 72]
slot value :None
slot number :4
U:[1, 2, 62] D:[2, 1, 80] L:[3, 4, 70] R:[4, 3, 72]
slot value :None
slot number :5
U:[1, 2, 62] D:[2, 1, 80] L:[3, 4, 70] R:[4, 3, 72]
```

and so on for all 9 objects appended to list. How can I make the variables slot1/slot2
refer to individual objects made?

I've tried passing the board object to slot constructor, and making slot constructor pass 'self' back to Board object. still the results for a single object are outputted for all. 
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

[edit] full code of the file : hope the indenting comes out right

```
import coords;

#store  hanndle position values

class Slot: #slot class<------------------------------------------------

    U = [1,2,"gridPosition"] #1 up
    D = [2,1,"gridPosition"] #2 down
    L = [3,4,"gridPosition"] #3 left
    R = [4,3,"gridPosition"] #4 right
    handles = [U,D,L,R] #handles 0/1/2/3

    tileValue = 0; #value 0 - 8
    tilePosition = 0; #slot 1 - 9
    overallStrain = 0; # |0-->+

    #Slot class constructor
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.setPosition(n);
        positions = coords.getLargeGridPosition(n);
        self.U[2] = positions[1]; self.D[2] = positions[2];
        self.L[2] = positions[3]; self.R[2] = positions[4];

        print("made slot object : "+str(self.getPosition()));
        print("handle values: ");
        self.getHandles();
        print(" - ");

    def getHandles(self):
        print(" U:"+str(self.U)+" D:"+str(self.D)+" L:"+str(self.L)+" R:"+str(self.R));

    #set/get position of slot(1-9)
    def setPosition(self,position):
        self.tilePosition = position;
    def getPosition(self):
        return self.tilePosition;

    #set/get tile value
    def setTileValue(self,value):
        self.TileValue = value;
    def getTileValue(self):
        return self.TileValue;

    #get handle(n) position value
    def getHandle(self,number):
        return self.handles[number]

    #get overall strain of tile
    def getTotalStrain(self):
        return self.totalStrain;
    #calculate total strain from strains of handles
    #def calculateOverallStrain(self):#<---------------
        #for handle in handles:
            #if


    #get linked tile,



class Board: #Boardclass<------------------------------------------------
    slots = []

    def __init__(self):
        slot1 = Slot(1); self.slots.append(slot1);
        slot2 = Slot(2); self.slots.append(slot2);
        slot3 = Slot(3); self.slots.append(slot3);
        slot4 = Slot(4); self.slots.append(slot4);
        slot5 = Slot(5); self.slots.append(slot5);
        slot6 = Slot(6); self.slots.append(slot6);
        slot7 = Slot(7); self.slots.append(slot7);
        slot8 = Slot(8); self.slots.append(slot8);
        slot9 = Slot(9); self.slots.append(slot9);

        print("\nprinting slot objects in list 'slot'\n");
        counter = 0;
        while counter < len(self.slots):
            print("slot number :"+str(self.slots[counter].getPosition()));
            print("slot value :"+str(self.slots[counter].getHandles()));
            counter +=1;


    #set tiles
    def setTiles(self,state):
        counter = 0;
        for slot in self.slots:
            slot.setTileValue(state[counter]);
            counter +=1;


    def getStrain(self,slot):
        tileValue = self.slots[slot].getTileValue();
        print("tile value:"+str(tileValue));
        print("handles:");
        self.slots[slot].getHandles();

        if tileValue != 0:
            linkedTiles = coords.getLinked(tileValue);
            print(str(linkedTiles));

            counter = 0;
            for l in linkedTiles:#for each linked tile
                if l != 0: #if not empty link

                    linkedTileSlot = [];#slot linked tile is set in

                    for slot in self.slots:
                        linkedTileValue = slot.getTileValue();
                        print(str(linkedTileValue));
                        if l == linkedTileValue:#found slot with linked tile
                            print("yes");
                            linkedTileSlot = slot; break;

                    ownHandle = slot.getHandle(counter);
                    print("own handle : "+str(ownHandle));
                    linkingHandle = linkedTileSlot.getHandle(ownHandle[1]-1);
                    print("linking handle : "+str(linkingHandle));
                    positions = [ownHandle[2],linkingHandle[2]]
                    print(str(positions));

                counter += 1;
```

Comment: Show us the rest of the `Slot` class. If `U`, `D`, `L`, `R` are defined on the class, they are, um, defined on the class and thus shared by all instances.

Comment: do you mean like static variables in Java? If so is there someway to make them instance variables?

Comment: Just saying, you don't need semicolons in Python; white-space dictates code-structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pavel says in the comments, anything defined at the class level is a class variable, shared between all instances. You need to define those variables within `__init__` by assigning them to `self`:

```
class Slot: #slot class<------------------------------------------------
  def __init__(self,n):    
    self.U = [1,2,"gridPosition"] #1 up
    self.D = [2,1,"gridPosition"] #2 down
    self.L = [3,4,"gridPosition"] #3 left
    self.R = [4,3,"gridPosition"] #4 right
    self.handles = [U,D,L,R] #handles 0/1/2/3

    self.tileValue = 0; #value 0 - 8
    self.tilePosition = 0; #slot 1 - 9
    self.overallStrain = 0; # |0-->+
```

You should also know that there are quite a few examples of extremely unidiomatic Python here. For example, the entire Board init should simply be:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.slots = [Slot(i+1) for i in range(10)]

    print("\nprinting slot objects in list 'slot'\n");
    for slot in self.slots:
        print("slot number :%s" % slot.getPosition());
        print("slot value :%d" slot.getHandles());
```

Also, it's discouraged to define getters and setters unless there is a very good reason, which you don't have here since you're just accessing the variable. You should assign to and return `self.position` and so on.

Comment: yes...self.handles = [U,D,L,R] needed changing toself.handles = [self.U,self.D,self.L,self.R] #handles 0/1/2/3 but otherwise it runs perfectly now... about the strange code, I've not used Python much and have been learning on the go. I hope to get better! thanks again.